# Restart Spree everytime you make a change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Just getting into Spree now. Is it true, you have to restart the server everytime you make a change to the CSS? Any strategic workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the reason it has to update by restarting is because my CSS overrides the main CSS which is Less, and can only be seen when I restart the server, and then my CSS is run through the initializers. Otherwise, if I just augment the Less framework for CSS, then it will update on refresh.